# Excel failed simple calculation

Tags: excel

What is wrong with Excel?
I tried this on 3 PCs and I receive the same result....

[image]

Comment: The short answer is that Excel seems to use binary floating-point arithmetic and, to be honest, I cannot remember the exact explanation from my studies...

Comment: Just select the 'scientific' or 'general' from the Home menu section of 'Number' instead of 'Number'

Comment: [here](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/floating-point-calculation-issues-excel/) is why. It's by design. You'll need to encapsule two arguments in paranthesis first.